# Borrowed money from a friend to pay College fee - Implications of not paying

Tags: united-states, repayment, private-lending

My wife is a US Citizen. She borrowed money from a friend to pay for her college.

She is unable to repay on time. She needs a bit more time, but unfortunately the lender is not ready to wait. He wants to file a complaint.  Can you explain me the laws of US and can this affect her career in future?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you might consider asking the lender to visit a mediator to try to reach an agreement. That could be much less expensive than dealing with it in court. Having a disinterested third-party may help both of you see the others' point of view and come to a deal.

Answer (score 5):

**Depending on the amount and what state you live in**, the "complaint" (aka lawsuit) would be filed in Civil Court or Small Claims Court.

Explaining the laws would really require Law.StackExchange.

The affect on her future of a *lost* lawsuit -- and therefore judgment against her for the money -- would be that companies which do a background check will see it and *possibly* not want to hire her (deeming her unreliable).  If the background check doesn't look for financial judgments, it won't have an impact on her career.